# JavaScript: Function to change images with onClick not working.

Tags: javascript

I have 6 pictures of the lovely Serena Williams, I've been researching how to change the images every time  I click on them. However the code is not working, please help me identify whether I've made a logic or syntax error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SerenaWilliams</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hGUyOlpoeB0/UROyeHgMXcI/AAAAAAAAAZ4/L32zLAQvQj0/s1600/Hot-Serena-Williams+_sexy+16.jpg" id="serenaGallery" onclick="changeImage" /> 
    </body>

   <script type="text/javascript">

       function changeImage() {

           var currentImage = document.getElementById("serenaGallery").src;
           var image1 = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hGUyOlpoeB0/UROyeHgMXcI/AAAAAAAAAZ4/L32zLAQvQj0/s1600/Hot-Serena-Williams+_sexy+16.jpg";
           var image2 = "http://usatthebiglead.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/serena-williams-is-big-boned.jpg";
           var image3 = "http://www.strangecosmos.com/images/content/109963.jpg";
           var image4 = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-HiJxcIjMmFg/UWo9JtbfCEI/AAAAAAAAF1g/aUU42F3V9Ic/s1600/Serena+Williams+Hot+2013+04.jpg";
           var image5 = "http://mystarclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Serena-Williams-is-a-Bikini-Babe.jpg";
           var image6 = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vCsx4sswzeM/UA5GtbEwJ1I/AAAAAAAAACE/tMiP_p-0rB0/s1600/serena+williams+tennis+ball+in+butt.jpg";

           if (currentImage==image1){ currentImage=image2; }
           if (currentImage==image2){ currentImage=image3; }
           if (currentImage==image3){ currentImage=image4; }
           if (currentImage==image4){ currentImage=image5; }
           if (currentImage==image5){ currentImage=image6; }
           else { currentImage=image1; }

        }

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` should be in `<head>` or `<body>`, not an immediate child of `<html>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to modify the *onclick* attribute so it will actually execute the function:

```
onclick="changeImage()"
```

The command

```
var currentImage = document.getElementById("serenaGallery").src;
```

just stores the *source* attribute of the image in a variable; it doesn't reference it.

Also, you have to change all `if` statements to `else if` or the function will change image1 to image2, then to image3, etc.

This would work:

```
var currentImage = document.getElementById("serenaGallery");

...

if (currentImage.src == image1){ currentImage.src=image2;}
else if (currentImage.src == image2){ currentImage.src=image3;}

...
```

Lastly, using an array for the image sources would allow you to condense the `if` statements into a single `for` loop. Not really needed for six images, but better if you want to add more.